# CSS how to change overflow of parent element?

Tags: html, css

How can i place div on an img element? Also i would like to do it slightly outside.

I have something like this:

```
<div class="slide">
    <div class="arrow">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer scelerisque ex eget ultricies blandit.</p>
    </div>
    <img src="http://boallen.com/assets/images/randbitmap_true.png">
</div>
```

And here is my css style:

```
    .arrow {
        max-width: 300px;
        background-color: #FAFAFA;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .arrow:after {
        left: 100%;
        bottom: 0px;
        content: " ";
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
        position: absolute;
        pointer-events: none;
        border-width: 15px;
        border-bottom: 30px solid #FAFAFA;
        border-right: 30px solid transparent;
    }
```

So how can i do this? to place my arrow div on an image slightly outside? and i don't want to set the image as background i need it to be in the img tag.

@update

keep in minde i dont want to change style of `.slide` element. and i have `overflow: hidden;` so how to make my `arrow` element to not be hidden ?

check it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/pyx3zx25/9/

**how to change overflow of parent element?**

Comment: your question is not clear. what do you want do here exactly?

Comment: have you tried defining a `div` with the image as the background of that `div`, and putting the other `div` inside it?

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you want to achieve, but have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/pyx3zx25/2/

Comment: here you have screenshote from my web: http://scr.hu/34xg/q2lmy

Answer (score 0):

You have given position absolute to the arrow div.
when you give top and left value to that; you can position it any where on the image.
try the below value,the div with text come inside the image,adjust the values according to your need.

```
.arrow {
            max-width: 300px;
            background-color: #FAFAFA;
            position: absolute;
            top:200px;
            left:100px;
}
```

you can add top:10px;
           left:0px;
i think those values will give you desired result

Comment: ok great, i set the value `top: -50px;` and it cut the part outside the image. i assumme its becouse of the parent containers style but i can not figure our with one

Answer (score 0):

Just use the 'negative value' on top and left.

```css
 .arrow {
            max-width: 300px;
            background-color: #FAFAFA;
            position: absolute;
            top:-10px;
            left:-10px;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it.

```
    .slide{
        position: relative;
        height: 521px;
        width: 521px;
    }

   .arrow {
            max-width: 300px;
            background-color: #FAFAFA;
            position: absolute;
            top:40%;
            left:20%;

    }
```

***[Update](http://jsfiddle.net/pyx3zx25/1/)***

Comment: oe its fine here http://jsfiddle.net/pyx3zx25/5/

but on my wordpress side its cut outside the image

Comment: you give the wrong value in  jsfiddle.net/pyx3zx25/5 that is -40pz you should do it -40px

Comment: i ubdated my question check it out